# What is happening that messes up my GROUP BY query?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

This is my Query:

```
select top 60 * from ABC_Sessions (nolock)   
where EntryDate > '06-22-2012 23:59:59'
GROUP BY TargetedID
```

then it gives me this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'BI_Sessions.SessionID' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You can't use SELECT * with GROUP BY. Can you explain what the group by is supposed to mean if you're selecting all rows? If you have two rows with the same TargetedID, what row do you want for EntryDate and the other columns? Please show sample data and desired results, instead of the invalid query you tried and the error it should be returning.

Comment: And what is your question? The error message seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `*` in your query expands to all the columns in your table.

```
select top 60 TargetedID, SessionID, ...
from ABC_Sessions (nolock)
where EntryDate > '06-22-2012 23:59:59'
GROUP BY TargetedID
```

As the error message states, it's not valid to select `SessionID` without an aggregate function (e.g. `MAX`).

This would work:

```
select top 60 TargetedID, MAX(SessionID) AS MaxSessionID
from ABC_Sessions (nolock)
where EntryDate > '06-22-2012 23:59:59'
GROUP BY TargetedID
```

Answer (score 1):

You used star `*` but not group by columns from `abc_sessions` table.
Using `GROUP BY` without any aggregate function looks strange for me.

What would you like to see?

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of theory: as the error says, you're not allowed to SELECT something that you have not at your disposal. 
So, when you use a simple SELECT / FROM / WHERE query, everything you have in your FROM tables is OK for you to select.

But if you use a GROUP BY, you're narrowing your view: anything you don't use in your GROUP BY is discarded (think it twice, it makes no sense to select data from several lines when you explicitly ask to group those lines).

Maybe you're confusing [GROUP BY](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7080.asp) and [ORDER BY](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7082.asp)?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting this error is because you are not using either sum/average/count/max/min or any similar functions in the select statement of yours. Once you use any of them, you won't get this error. ex :
select top 60 TargetedID, MAX(EntryDate) 
from ABC_Sessions (nolock)
where EntryDate > '06-22-2012 23:59:59'
GROUP BY TargetedID